# How to I hardcode/alter test results from autoconf when cross-compiling NTP for QNX?

Tags: cross-compiling, autoconf, ntp, qnx, qnx-neutrino

I am attempting to cross-compile NTP for armv7-unknown-nto-qnx from i686-pc-linux-gnu.

So far, I have built up the following command:

```
CC=/opt/qnx660/host/linux/x86/usr/bin/qcc LD=/opt/qnx660/host/linux/x86/usr/bin/ntoarmv7-ld  CFLAGS="-static -Vgcc_ntoarmv7le" ../configure --host=armv7-unknown-nto-qnx --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu --prefix=$(pwd)/output --with-yielding-select=yes
```

This seems to get me most of the way there; however, the compiler ends up throwing `../../../sntp/libevent/signal.c:255:17: error: 'SA_RESTART' undeclared (first use in this function)`. In this and every other instance of SA_RESTART, the configure-defined constant HAVE_SIGACTION ifdefs out the problem code. Looking into config.log, I found this:

```
configure:24569: checking for sigaction
17307configure:24569: /opt/qnx660/host/linux/x86/usr/bin/qcc -std=gnu99 -std=gnu99 -o conftest -static -Vgcc_ntoarmv7le   conftest.c -lsocket  >&5
17308configure:24569: $? = 0
17309configure:24569: result: yes
```

I think this is a false positive.

I'm looking for either a way to correct the ./configure tests by further specifying my environment or a way to specify the result of the test.

I am aware that I could just modify the config.h after the auto-testing, but this is not a valid solution for my application.

Comment: The best way would be to correct the configure script for the sigaction test to include a reference to `SA_RESTART`, possibly such a patch would be accepted into upstream. But as only a few tests use signal.h, you could just get silly and try to break it, maybe add a `-Dsigaction=wtf/bbq` to the CC variable?

Comment: The define in the generated header file supersedes the command line definition/undefinition :(

Answer (score 0):

`SA_RESTART` is not supported in QNX. Only `SA_NOCLDSTOP` and `SA_SIGINFO` are supported.

For more info, see this reference: http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino_lib_ref%2Fs%2Fsigaction.html

Comment: ...yes...I know...that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To disable the function check for sigaction, export ac_cv_func_sigaction=no in your environment before calling configure.

However, there is nothing wrong with the configure here -- QNX does support sigaction(), and thus configure is correctly returning 'yes'.   This is a bug in libevent where it is assuming that all operating systems that support sigaction() also support SA_RESTART, which is not true on QNX.  sigaction is used in other places in the ntp software, and blanket disabling all sigaction calls may have unintended side effects.   Instead, I suggest you consider patching libevent for proper QNX support; the fine folks at QNX have provided a patch through their pkgsrc tree, [available here](http://community.qnx.com/viewvc/HEAD_660/pkgsrc/devel/libevent/?root=pkgsrc&system=exsy1011).